# Why does referencing a variable in a join predicate force nested loops?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, query-performance

I came across this issue [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30601957/73226) and couldn't find any discussion of it online.

The query below

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(1) = '';

WITH T
     AS (SELECT name + @S AS name2,
                *
         FROM   master..spt_values)
SELECT *
FROM   T T1
       INNER JOIN T T2
         ON T1.name2 = T2.name2;
```

Always gets a nested loops plan

[image]

Attempting to force the issue with `INNER HASH JOIN` or `INNER MERGE JOIN` hints produces the following error.

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
>   defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints
>   and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

I found a workaround which does allow hash or merge joins to be used - wrapping the variable in an aggregate. The plan generated is significantly lower costed (19.2025 vs 0.261987)

```
DECLARE @S2 VARCHAR(1) = '';

WITH T
     AS (SELECT name + (SELECT MAX(@S2)) AS name2,
                *
         FROM   spt_values)
SELECT *
FROM   T T1
       INNER JOIN T T2
         ON T1.name2 = T2.name2;
```

[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour? and is there a better workaround than the one that I found? (that perhaps doesn't require the extra execution plan branches)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've tried your query on a SQL 2012 instance and trace flag 4199 seems to fix the issue. With it enabled I get a merge join for a total cost of 0.24 and none of the extra branches.

The specific KB article for this issue is [Performance issues occur when the join predicate in your query has outer reference columns in SQL Server 2005 or in SQL Server 2008](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976410)

[image]

To further qualify, TF 4199 enables all optimizer fixes.  See [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974006) for more information. Enabling everything at once can have weird side-effects, so if you can find a specific fix it might be better to enable the fix on it's own.

You can enable a trace flag on a per query basis using `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4199)`;

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but seeing the answer wasn't super definitive, thought I would post a workaround I found.  Not sure why query optimizer balks at `HASH`, but I think it doesn't like `MERGE` because it does not have sorted input.  On 2012/14,

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(1) = '';

    WITH T
        AS (SELECT TOP (2147483647)
                name + @S AS name2,
                *
            FROM   master..spt_values
            ORDER BY name + @S)
    SELECT *
    FROM   T T1
           INNER JOIN T T2
             ON T1.name2 = T2.name2;
```

produces the following plan:

[image]

Forcing `TOP` and the `ORDER BY` in the cte seems to give the optimizer enough knowledge about the dataset to perform the `MERGE JOIN`.